# Why am I getting a "java.util.NoSuchElementException"?

Tags: java

Here the error i am getting...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Maze.Map.readFile(Map.java:60)
at Maze.Map.<init>(Map.java:23)
at Maze.Board.<init>(Board.java:16)
at Maze.Maze.<init>(Maze.java:15)
at Maze.Maze.main(Maze.java:9)
```

Below is my code!

```
package Maze;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Maze 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        new Maze();
    }

    public Maze()

    {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setTitle("Maze Game");

        f.add(new Board());
        f.setSize(464, 485);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

---

```
package Maze;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    private Timer timer;

    private Map m;

    public Board()
    {
        m = new Map();

        timer = new Timer(25, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        for(int y = 0; y < 14; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 14; x++)
            {
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("g"))
                {
                    g.drawImage(m.getFloor(), x * 32, y * 32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("w"))
                {
                    g.drawImage(m.getWall(), x * 32, y * 32, null);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
package Maze;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Map 
{
    private Scanner m;
    private String Map[] = new String[14];
    private Image floor,
                  wall;    

    public Map()
    {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C://Test//MazeGame//floor.jpg");
        floor = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C://Test//MazeGame//wall.jpg");
        wall = img.getImage();

        openFile();
        readFile();
        closeFile();
    }

    public Image getFloor()
    {
        return floor;
    }

    public Image getWall()
    {
        return wall;
    }

    public String getMap(int x, int y)
    {
        String index = Map[y].substring(x, x + 1);
        return index;
    }

    public void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            m = new Scanner(new File("C://Test//MazeGame//Map.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print("Error Loading Map!");
            }
    }

    public void readFile()
    {
        while(m.hasNext())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            {
                Map[i] = m.next();
            }
        }
    }



    public void closeFile()
    {
        m.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, first please help us: which line is `Map.java:60`, line 60 of your Map class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is your error (you haven't told us which line is line 60 of your Map class, the line that is causing your exception), but this is dangerous code:

```
while(m.hasNext())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        Map[i] = m.next();
    }
}
```

You're calling `hasNext()` once per loop iteration, but calling `next()` 14 times! There should be a strict 1 to 1 correlation in that each `next()` should match with a preceding `hasNext()`.

---

Also, there's no reason for the nested for loop since the while loop will handle all you need. You probably would get by with something like:

```
int i = 0;
while(m.hasNext()) {
   Map[i] = m.next();
   i++;
}
```

But it would be safer to use an ArrayList rather than an array.

---

As an aside, please learn and follow Java coding conventions. Methods and fields/variables/parameters should all start with a lower-case letter, so Map[i] is not allowed, but rather should be map[i]. Doing this will help us to better understand and follow your code and thus help you.

Comment: The code you have shown contains shows this error... at Maze.Map.readFile(Map.java:60)

Comment: Now that you have told me that a next() should match a preceding Next! i think i can sort it out!! thanks

Comment: I still cant do it :-( i seriously need to practice more!! I am still unsure what to do with the code you have mentioned!

Comment: @SeanCoyne: what you need to realize, and what is being pointed out, is you check if it `hasNext()` but then run up the map 14x. What if there's only one more element? Check if it `hasNext` and then do something with that element, then check if it `hasNext` again and continue to repeat.

Comment: ahh so what your saying is i am trying to check something that may not be there? and therefore not letting it run? thanks for helping BobbyDigital!!!

Comment: You should create a flag (e.g. boolean isRunning) and then check hasNext() before every next() -- if it's false, set isRunning=false and break from your inner loop.

Comment: @BarneyGovan Why an extra flag that is supposed to have the same value as `m.hasNext()`?

Comment: @SeanCoyne: Also, you shouldn't even have a for loop with a nested while loop. Instead of an array of String why not use a `List<String>` such as an `ArrayList<String>`, and fill it via a `while (...)` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help everyone!!! Thanks for the answer Hovercraft, and thanks for the advise! :-)

Comment: @Ingo Mainly for readability (ie. for the programmer who maintains your code who may be a psychotic axe-wielding maniac); though your suggestion would have the same effect.